# How to pick random sample while ensuring data is unique at primary key level

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with data at user-date level i.e.

```
userID date        eventID
A      2021-06-01   123
B      2021-06-01   342
C      2021-06-01   23487
A      2021-06-01   234221
D      2021-06-01   34245
A      2021-06-01   09834
```

I want to randomly pick 20% of the rows and hence used

```
select *
from table
where rand() <= (1/5)
```

Output has 20% of rows from the input table but there are some users who are repeating. I want to ensure that there is only 1 row per user and for users with multiple entries on the same day, the pick is randomized.

Comment: If there is one row per user, there is not much to "randomize" in therms of multiple entries on one day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` for this:

```
select t.* except (seqnum)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by userid order by rand()) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where 1=1
qualify row_number() over (order by seqnum order by rand()) < 0.2 * count(*) over ();
```

What is this doing?  This is randomizing the rows for each user, arbitrarily assigning a sequential number to them.

Then, it is assigning a *new* ordering by the sequential number.  So, the "first" row for each user will be fetched first, and so on.  This balances the number of rows for each user.

The `qualify()` then chooses 20% of the rows.